# Accidentally deleted my encrypted coldstorage drive. Can I recover it somehow? diskutil cs delete MAC

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, partition, hfs+, diskutil

The hard drive connection broke in my macbook pro. I used a sata to usb cable and put it on the mac, it still didnt boot.

I went into Recovery. I believe the drive originally had 3 partitions. One was a recovery, one was the mac drive, and I didnt remember what the third was.

I read online without understanding, that I cant recover my files from it because it was a cold storage drive. In mac's disk utility, it kept asking for a password that I never remembered setting. I then ran 'diskutil cs delete Macintosh HD'.

..Everything was gone. Including my ability to reinstall the OS on the drive to save my data.

Can I somehow restore that coldstorage partition? Then reinstall the OS to get my data? I haven't touched it since I ran that command.

I also am able to view my old Recovery Partition using recovery software. Inside, I found a file called encryptedroot.plist.wipekey if this helps my case.

Edit: Plugging it into windows it shows this:
[image: It didn't used to say RAW]

[image: Mac DiskUtil]

Edit2: I think I figured out what the password might be. But I can't get back to the point where it asks me. Am I out of luck or is there someway to recreate what I deleted.

Diskutil logs from before I ran that command:
[image: If UIDs are needed]

[image]

[image: Recovery software on recovery partition]